python autocompletion with corfu not work on emacs29.4
I try to setup python auto completion with corfu, my emacs is 29.4, my init.el as below:
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)

;(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 200)
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Monospace" :height 180)
(when window-system  (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 0 0)
  (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 120 30))

(load-theme 'manoj-dark)
(setq warning-minimum-level :emergency)

(setq python-shell-interpreter "~/work/venvs/py312/bin/python3")
  (setq major-mode-remap-alist
 '((c-mode . c-ts-mode)
   (cpp-mode . cpp-ts-mode)
   (python-mode . python-ts-mode)
  )
)

(use-package eglot
  :init
  (fset #'jsonrpc--log-event #'ignore) ;; performance boost
  :hook
  (python-ts-mode . eglot-ensure)
  (js-ts-mode . eglot-ensure)
  (ruby-ts-mode . eglot-ensure)
  (json-ts-mode . eglot-ensure)
  (yaml-ts-mode . eglot-ensure)
  (dockerfile-ts-mode . eglot-ensure)
  (css-mode . eglot-ensure)
  (html-mode . eglot-ensure))

(setq completion-auto-help 'always)
(corfu
 ;; Optional customizations
 :custom
 (corfu-cycle t) ;; Enable cycling for `corfu-next/previous'
 (corfu-auto t) ;; Enable auto completion
 (corfu-quit-at-boundary 'separator) ;; Automatically quit at word boundary
 (corfu-quit-no-match 'separator) ;; Automatically quit if there is no match
 (corfu-scroll-margin 5) ;; Use scroll margin
 (corfu-auto-delay 0.0)
 (corfu-auto-prefix 1)
 (corfu-on-exact-match 'quit)
 :hook (before-save-hook . corfu-quit)
 :load-path "straight/build/corfu/extensions"
 :config
 (require 'corfu-history)
 (corfu-history-mode 1)
 (savehist-mode 1)
 (add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'corfu-history)
 )

(advice-add 'corfu--candidates :around
            (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              (message "corfu--candidates called with args: %S" args)
              (let ((result (apply orig-fun args)))
                (message "corfu--candidates returned: %S" result)
                result)))

(setq global-corfu-minibuffer
      (lambda ()
        (not (or (bound-and-true-p mct--active)
                 (bound-and-true-p vertico--input)
                 (eq (current-local-map) read-passwd-map)))))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-local corfu-auto nil)
            (corfu-mode)))


When I type print(, I do see the function prototype popup then overwrite by some other message immediately like below:


Depending on where is installed your python, you may need to add its path
to emacs execution-path. Keep in mind the packages eglot and lsp-mode
does the same thing, so you don't need to enable both in your configuration,
experiment with them one at the time. Same for pylsp, ruff is replacing
some other checkers, e.g. flake8, so again do not enable both, otherwise
you will get double the number of errors.

Please pare down the configuration to what is essential to reproduce the problem. Posting your whole init file is not helpful.

yes, simplified the init.el, add python path,

See this page and this one
with explanations how to configure corfu, with examples. It is a good idea to add orderless
to your configuration, as is indicated in last link.
